# Machlokes between Beis Hillel and Beis Shamai

Tags: history, machlokes, hillel

Why did unresolved disputes begin specifically at this time? Why were there no unresolved disputes before?

Comment: The semicha machlokes was long before

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Where do we learn that there were none before?  You can [edit] your answer to add more information.  Thanks.

Comment: Interestingly, the rabbi who gave one of the parsha shiurs that I attended just last night made the same comment that Hillel and Shammai introduced Machlokes to Israel.

Comment: Hillel and Shammai were not the first to have Halachic arguments, Yosi ben Yoezer and Yosi ben Yochanan were. see here http://www.torahlab.org/images/uploads/Pirkei_Avos_-_Perek_1.pdf

Comment: @Menachem please write where in the document specifically this is found

Comment: @annex hillel and shamai were the ones to introduce mochlokes on a large scale and from then on machlokes in learning became the de facto norm

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight: page 5

Answer (score 1):

the reason is that until then questions were brought to the sanhedrin, which followed "acharei rabim lehatos", therefore any opinion that didnt win the majority vote was discarded.

however King Herod nullified the sanhedrin. therefore when hillel and shamai had different opinions, even though they followed majority in their own school, they couldn't come together for a global ruling.

Comment: But Beis Hillel was there with him!

Comment: see Shabbos 14 or so

Comment: what's your new understanding of the Gemara?

Answer (score 1):

Tosafos  *ד"ה יוסי*  in Chagiga Daf ט"ז says that the Machlokes between Beit Shammai and Beit Hillel was caused by students who didn't do enough שימוש by their teachers.

Essentially the students didn't spend enough time studying, possibly out of laziness, as we see Hillel accusing בני בתירא of doing in פסחים on Daf ס"ו.

Hillel and Shammai themselves only argued about 4 issues, as enumerated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillel_and_Shammai).

Before that there was only one unsolved argument that went on for 5 generations; whether one can do Shmicha on a Korban on Yom Tov, as mentioned in [Chagiga Daf ט"ז](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l2b02.htm).